# How to replace deprecated gulp-karma with new version of karma?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

Currently I am using gulp-karma for unit-testing in JS, but the current version is deprecated. 
How can I replace this code so I can use the new version recommended?

Old version:
    var karma = require('gulp-karma');

```
var testFiles = [
  'client/todo.js',
  'client/todo.util.js',
];

gulp.task('test', function() {
  // Be sure to return the stream 
  return gulp.src(testFiles)
    .pipe(karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: 'run'
    }))
    .on('error', function(err) {
      // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero 
      throw err;
    });
});
```

New recommended version (but not using pipes):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').server;

gulp.task('tests', function(done) {
return karma.start({
      configFile: __dirname + '/test/karma.conf.js',
      singleRun: true
    }, done);
});
```

I specify I need to use pipes, but I always get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a quick research, so I'm not 100% sure that this is going to work, but Id give it a try.

**Requirements**
  * Promises support (native or via a third party library)
  * [stream-from-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-from-promise) => `npm install stream-from-promise --save-dev`

First wrap your karma server into a promise (some third party libraries also offer [a safer `promisify` fn](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) for this):

```
function startKarma(){
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
    karma.start({
      configFile: __dirname + '/test/karma.conf.js',
      singleRun: true
    }, function(error){
      return error ? reject(error) : resolve();
    });
}
```

Now create a function to create a stream out of a promise:

```
var StreamFromPromise = require("stream-from-promise");

function makeStream( promise ){
  return StreamFromPromise.obj( promise );
});
```

And now let's write your task:

```
gulp.task('tests', function() {
  return gulp.src(testFiles)
  .pipe( makeStream( startKarma() ))
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero 
    throw err;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').server;
var testFiles = [
  'client/todo.js',
  'client/todo.util.js',
];
gulp.task('tests', function(done) {
  return karma.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true,
    files: testFiles
  }, done);
});
```